# How to simplify C# code with IF conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there some decision to simplify C# code with many IF conditions?
I think many if conditions need many proccess time
Here is my code:

```
public double volume;
public double progressBar;
If(volumeValue >= 10 && volumeValue <20)
{
ProgressBar +=1;
}
If(volumeValue >= 20 && volumeValue <30)
{
ProgressBar +=1;
}
If(volumeValue >= 30 && volumeValue <40)
{
ProgressBar +=1;
}
If(volumeValue >= 40 && volumeValue <50)
{
ProgressBar +=1;
} 
If(volumeValue >= 50)
{
ProgressBar +=1;
}
```

Comment: All conditions are mutually exclusive, than it should be only `ProgressBar +=1;`

Comment: Using "else if" would save you evaluating multiple if statements. If you are performing the same operation in all cases - then you could have a single if statement & OR the conditions together. In your case here it appears a single "if (volumeValue >= 10)" - would work.

Comment: Where do you set value to `volumeValue ` ?

Comment: Doesn't this mean if `(value >= 10) ProgressBar++;`?

Comment: Assuming your real code (I'm guessing this is not real code, since you've got `If` rather than `if`) is more complex, perhaps post that instead of an oversimplified example - the answer to whether or not this can be simplified depends on exactly what the `if` statements are and what is happening within each condition.

Comment: @Bob This is absolutely unsuitable for Code Review by lack of context. Please refer to [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before making further recommendations.

Comment: _many if conditions need many proccess time_ No, the processing time is and will be meaningless in 99% of anything you'll ever do. It is all about coding and debugging time for the next couple of years

Comment: @Mast "s there some decision to simplify C# code with many IF conditions? I think many if conditions need many proccess time Here is my code:" Does it say, that his prog. doesnt work ?

Comment: If every situation will increase the `ProgressBar` anyway, why have the `if`s anyway?

Comment: @Bob If you want more information than that, take a look at the [FAQ: A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915)

Comment: @Mast I've read it and it says also that, there are question on-topic on both sites, so that means in my oppinion , that's also suitable for Code Review.

Comment: @Bob please do not make recommendations for migration to sites you have limited experience. Code Review has strict migration guidelines.

Comment: This look like a classic duplicate. It's a 1rst year  clasic question about range and int. One Virtual reward for the one that find it before the end of my lunch.

Comment: And it's look like is a simple (int)volumeValue /10

Comment: @Bob With this particular question it's clear that the code in the question is not the OP's actual, real code, as you have the `If` vs. `if` issue and also `ProgressBar` vs. `progressBar`, so this question would get closed on Code Review directly, as it's currently written.

Comment: @SimonForsberg yes you are right, but based on his question ...

Comment: @Bob The topic itself, about simplifying if-statements, is absolutely a good fit for Code Review. But I would have guessed that the OP will just see "Oh, I should copy-paste this exact question to this site instead" and then it would be closed on Code Review, leading to unwanted experience for both OP and Code Review. The question itself is not the only requirement [for a question to be on-topic on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the code also matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `else if` to simplify this code:

```
if (volumeValue >= 10)
{
    if (volumeValue < 20)
    {
        ProgressBar += 1;
    }
    else if (volumeValue < 30)
    {
        ProgressBar += 1;
    }
    else if (volumeValue < 40)
    {
        ProgressBar += 1;
    }
    else if (volumeValue < 50)
    {
        ProgressBar += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ProgressBar += 1;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't currently serve any purpose because only one of these will ever execute anyway, so you could just do:

```
if (volumeValue >= 10)
{
    ProgressBar += 1;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Corrected an issue identified by Karan whereby `volumeValue`s lower than 10 would cause an unwanted execution of code

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see (unless I'm looking at it wrong) the condition is this:

```
public double volume;
public double progressBar;

If(volumeValue >= 10)
{
ProgressBar +=1;
}
```

It's only this one that will execute. Anything else in your if statements already is equal or bigger than 10